# Proxmox KVM fails to start

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, proxmox, xeon, intel-vt-x

My new server is Fujitsu Primergy RX1330 M1 with Intel® Xeon® Processor E3-1220, running either Proxmox V4 or Proxmox V3.4 i have the following problem.

When i create a new virtual machine, during the start of the VM i get the error :

```
TASK ERROR: start failed: command '/usr/bin/kvm -id 100 -chardev 'socket,id=qmp,path=/var/run/qemu-server/100.qmp,server,nowait' -mon 'chardev=qmp,mode=control' -vnc unix:/var/run/qemu-server/100.vnc,x509,password -pidfile /var/run/qemu-server/100.pid -daemonize -smbios 'type=1,uuid=38bd036e-4299-4e09-9b72-d02182812c25' -name prox -smp '1,sockets=1,cores=1,maxcpus=1' -nodefaults -boot 'menu=on,strict=on,reboot-timeout=1000' -vga cirrus -cpu kvm64,+lahf_lm,+x2apic,+sep -m 512 -k en-us -cpuunits 1000 -device 'piix3-usb-uhci,id=uhci,bus=pci.0,addr=0x1.0x2' -device 'usb-tablet,id=tablet,bus=uhci.0,port=1' -device 'virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3' -iscsi 'initiator-name=iqn.1993-08.org.debian:01:32f0f95336c' -drive 'file=/var/lib/vz/template/iso/proxmox-ve_4.0-0d8559d0-17.iso,if=none,id=drive-ide2,media=cdrom,aio=native'
-device 'ide-cd,bus=ide.1,unit=0,drive=drive-ide2,id=ide2,bootindex=200'
-drive 'file=/var/lib/vz/images/100/vm-100-disk-1.qcow2,if=none,id=drive-ide0,format=qcow2,aio=native,cache=none,detect-zeroes=on'
-device 'ide-hd,bus=ide.0,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0,id=ide0,bootindex=100'
-netdev 'type=tap,id=net0,ifname=tap100i0,script=/var/lib/qemu-server/pve-bridge,downscript=/var/lib/qemu-server/pve-bridgedown'
-device 'e1000,mac=3A:C0:2A:97:6D:2D,netdev=net0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x12,id=net0,bootindex=300'' failed: exit code 1
```

I have tried multiple ISO both 32 and 64 bits, the BIOS Version is 2.15.1236, the VT-d and Intel Virtualization Technology are enabled.

Answer (score 4):

Select the VM, go to options tab, find KVM hardware virtualisation, edit and uptick enabled.